# Kubernetes pull image from private insecure registry fails

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I have an unsecured private docker registry hosted on a vm server (vm1). I am trying to create a k8s deployment from an image pushed on to this registry. Surprising the docker pull command works fine since I have configured /etc/docker/daemon.json with insecure-registries.

The detailed error through the kubectl describe command is as below. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Thanks.

```
Failed to pull image "vm1:5000/temp/leads:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "vm1:5000/temp/leads:latest": failed to resolve reference "vm1:5000/temp/leads:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://vm1:5000/v2/temp/leads/manifests/latest": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

The docker pull command is

```
docker pull vm1:5000/temp/leads:latest
```

The k8s manifest file is as follows

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  namespace: oleads
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app
          image: vm1:5000/temp/leads:latest
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu: 0.5
            limits:
              memory: "512Mi"
              cpu: 0.5
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8980
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Comment: Where is the Kubernetes cluster running, on `vm1` as well, or on the host, or ...? From inside the cluster, can you resolve `vm1` to the IP of the host?

Comment: No the kubernetes cluster is running on a different node. Yes hostname to ip address resolution seems to be working since the docker pull command worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the kubernetes engine I am using k3s uses a different container runtime. It uses containerd instead of docker.
With k3s the config for using private registries is different. It is mentioned [here](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/private-registry).

The config I had to add in `/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml` file is

```
mirrors:
  vm1:5000:
    endpoint:
      - "http://vm1:5000"
```

Restarting the k3s service after adding this file resolved the issue and k8s was able to pull the image from my private insecured docker registry.

Answer (score -1):

we had the same issue , the solution could be adding the insecure registry with docker deamon.

### Activity on all nodes

---

create a file in : /etc/docker/daemon.json and add the insecure registry details :

```
{ "insecure-registries":["vm1:5000"] }
```

and `restart docker on all nodes` .

Comment: I had already done this as I mentioned in my post